# ActionBarSherlock TabPageIndicator with ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener - tab is stuck

Tags: android, android-viewpager, actionbarsherlock

I am running the example code provided with ABS (SampleTabsDefault). I added the OnPageChangeListener as shown below, now the TabPageIndicator is always stuck on the first tab even though the tab content changes. Am I doing something wrong?

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simple_tabs);

```
    mAdapter = new GoogleMusicAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);

    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener changeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {}

       @Override
       public void onPageSelected(int i) {}

       @Override
       public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {}
    };

    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(changeListener);
    mIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(changeListener);
}
```

Comment: I found a simple solution for this issue. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28181696

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that setting a change listener was overriding the code responsible for switching tabs. I could have subclassed the ABS class, but elected to switch to a TitlePageIndicator which does not have any issues with setting the listener..