# Viewpager's indicator is not moving

Tags: android

I am using pager sliding tab strip : https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/

**With following lines:**

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            pager =  (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
            tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            tabs.setViewPager(pager);
        }
```

**MyPagerAdapter:**

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return (position == 0)? "Users" : "Chats" ;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return (position == 0)?  new RandomsFragment() : new ChatsFragment() ;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

**Xml:**

```
<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    app:pstsIndicatorColor="#0B0B16"
    app:pstsShouldExpand="true" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Everything is working fine with at above code.But I need to listen tab changes,for achive this I changed my `onCreate` method to this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        pager =  (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
              public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
              public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}
              public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                  Log.w("Tab Selected","Position:"+position);
          }
    });
    }
```

With this code my code is working but tab indicator is not moving.

**You can see it here:**

[image]

I am in chats tab but indicator is still on the users tab.How can i fix this ? If I don't use `setOnPageChangeListener` it is moving.

Comment: Still not working for me. Any other solution. This library sucks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the problem is `pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener())` because the tabs itself are set as OnPageChangeListener.

Do that  `tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() ... )`

Answer (score 2):

When you call `setOnPageChangeListener` you're overwriting the one set by the library `PagerSlidingTabStrip` which is why it is not updating the indicator with the tab change. The `PagerSlidingTabStrip` should expose a method for you to listen for tab changes, I expect it already exists as it looks very similar to the official example code.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I was struck with the same problem, the indicator wasn't move with the ViewPager. Searched on Internet and at last I found my mistake:
I was using

```
ViewPager.setOnChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

but we have to use this listener for the Indicator, so I removed this listener from ViewPager and used the listener with my defined PageIndicator like below: and that worked fine.

```
pageIndicator.setAdapter(viewPager);
pageIndicator.setOnChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```